# bubble chart width and height set dynamically from json data in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I want to set the width and height of bubble chart according to number nodes.as the nodes increase the size is increases but i cant understand in which ratio my width and height is increasing. I have fixed size of nodes.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5xLjy1ra/1/ here I am getting width and height from the diameter.I want ,when i increase the number of nodes the size should be increase.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust the size of your svg, after adding more nodes, just select the svg again and set the width and height attributes. You can also create your nodes with specific radius.  Say you define `var r = 50;`, and your svg has initial width of `var width = 500;` then after adding one node, you can increase the width by

```
d3.select("svg").
  attr("width", width + (2*r));
```

You can also get the current radius of your nodes by doing

```
d3.select("circle").attr("r");
```

and use that to adjust your svg width and height.

Comment: thanks for your reply,The problem is width and height increase but the diameter is still constant.I also want to update the diameter.for example my current  diameter = 500; for 30 nodes, when I increase the nodes to 40.how i will increase my diameter?

Comment: You can update diameter (since you have declared it globally) to any value you like, when you update the number of nodes.  But you will also have to make sure that the SVG width and height are updated as I described above.

Comment: i am updating diameter but i don't know the exact way to update the diameter.currently i am calculating the number of nodes and multiply it with 40, so if i have 20 nodes and multiply it with 40(diameter = 40 * 20 = 800),the radius of individual is 91.547.now if increase the number of nodes to 30(diameter = 40 * 30 = 1200) the radius of individual is 109.937. i want to fix the radius ratio of individual which is a challenge for me

Comment: You can try this: from your fiddle, i get a radius of about 39px, which is a diameter of 78.  Since your largest row has 5 circles, I'd use that as a reference.  So that row takes 5*78 pixels = 390.  The svg is 500 wide, which gives you a ratio 390/500 = 0.78.  So when you add a new node and you want to keep this ratio, then now you do 6*78 = 468, and width becomes 468/0.78 = 600.  Setting the svg width and height to 600 should keep the circles the same size, after you add a single cirlce.  I think this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes you got my point thanks,the solution you gave me is for: when I declare my svg width = 500 and height = 500. Now suppose initially i have no idea about the number of nodes.my json has any number of nodes from 5 to 100.so how i will set initial svg width and height.

Comment: my problem is initially I have no idea about diameter,width and height, I will set all these three parameters on the bases of number of nodes in my json)